# Delete rows and shift up for with multiple words

Tags: database, excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a way to delete all rows and shift cells up.

The column contains various words. Among them I would like to delete few words (such as "GT", "ST", "Food" - altogether 10 different words). I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of words for AutoFilter criteria.

```
dim crit as variant
crit = array("GT", "ST", "Food")
with worksheets("sheet1")
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=crit, operator:=xlfiltervalues
        with .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
            if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
                .specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).entirerow.delete
            end if
        end with
    end with
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
end with
```